# "TypeError: isInteger is not a function"

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to figure out what is causing this type error.

I have a method which checks if a list of numbers contains a decimal or not, and formats it accordingly.

```
  numberColumn(key, label, formatted) {
    const digits = formatted && this.numbers.every(number => number[key].isInteger()) ? '0' : '2';
    return Object.assign(this.normalColumn(key, label), {
      template: {
        type: 'number',
        format: {
          minimumFractionDigits: digits,
          maximumFractionDigits: digits
        },
        foot: sum
      }
    });
  },
```

This method is used in a computed property like so:

```
  selectableFields() {
    return [
      {
      this.numberColumn('numOfUsers', 'Number of users', true),
      this.numberColumn('timeLogged', 'Time logged, false)
      }
    ];
  },
```

So in this case "Number of users" is formatted so that it will show a single number instead of decimals (eg. 0), while timeLogged is not formatted and will show decimals (eg. 0.0).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
Number.isInteger(yourNumber)
```

instead of calling isInteger() on your value.